# Strange DNS error

Tags: domain-name-system

Google reports me several strange errors on a subdomain of my site : `frequence-radio.com`
(the subdomain with the issue is `en-directo.frequence-radio.com` )

[Screenshot of the google console here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTqdF.jpg)

On all my other subdomains, I have no issues (they have the same configuration) Just `http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com` suffers this DNS problem although i have the same config for several years.
 My hoster (OVH) is telling me they don't have any problem on their side.

I run a test on dnssy.com and i did not see any issue with `frequence-radio.com`, with `en-directo.frequence-radio.com` i have an error

> Nameservers listed at parent: No nameservers found at parent nameserver.  Fail

But other websites i checked seems to have this answer too, perhaps it's normal ?

thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

If it is an off and on issue like that, then it is going to be your DNS provider. You mentioned that you haven't changed your records and have other domains setup the same so it would be the DNS provider or Google reading the records.

Using mxtoolbox.com everything looks fine right now also, A record lookup works and the DNS servers return correctly.

Answer (score -1):

This is definitely a DNS problem with your site. It may not be your site though, it maybe a resource the page uses.

After running a pingdom (http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) scan I got the below.

[image]

these are obviously the different languages at the bottom of the page, all seem to be fine but the final one "http://clients1.google.com/generate_204" does not load. It receives a white page so this might be your problem. I tried to find the resource that uses this, it's possibly the search bar but I can't be 100% sure.

Perhaps updating the search bar might fix this problem?

To make sure google can access your page go to "fetch as google" and click "fetch and render" in search console. If this fetches your page correctly there is no current problem.

Your server connectivity is 100% so that means that your hosting company won't be able to tell you much - from my experience.

ALSO TO NOTE*

While looking at your site I found the following:

Broken URL's

http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com/frecuencias-punto-radio-logrono.html
http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com/frecuencias-somosradio-logrono.html
http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com/frecuencias-radio-6.html
http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com/frecuencias-radio-castilla---la-mancha.html
http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com/frecuencias-radio-penarroya.html
http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com/frecuencias-litoral-fm-almunecar.html
http://en-directo.frequence-radio.com/frecuencias-radio-arnedo---onda-rioja.html

Comment: Thanks ! I removed the search bar and will see if there is a change !